# Ignore failed data source in SSRS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a report that runs one query in 9 different Oracle databases. If one of these databases is down, the whole report bombs. Is there any way to set it so it ignores this failure and proceeds with the rest of the report?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do what you're wanting within RS, but here's my idea:

If you can call from a SQL database -

Set up linked servers on a sql server.

Wrap the call in a stored procedure and return an alternate data set if the call fails to the linked server.

You could probably do something similar if there is an oracle server you can use.